# ngRoute white Page after Refresh page is showed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes, ngroute

i have a problem with my Angular Site. I create this with ngRoute but when i click on the Link a white page is showed only after refresh the page the content is there. In the DevTools of the browser we can see the html code of the site (when the white page is there) but nothing is showed.

dhnatura.codeanarchy.net

There u can see the problem click on "Unternehmen" and the white page will appear and after refresh the page it works.

Routing:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('dhnatura')
    .config(routeConfig);

  function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/company', {
          templateUrl: 'app/company/company.html',
          controller: 'CompanyController',
          controllerAs: 'company'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }

})();
```

Link in HTML:

```html
<a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#/company">Unternehmen</a>
```

Maybe i missed something to configure?

Comment: I dont find any problem. For me the page is loading properly. I checked in firefox if it helps.

Comment: wow ok in Chrome it works also but in Safari this is not working? Strange behavior

Comment: But in Chrome it works also not perfekt, for example the footer on the 'Unternehmen" Page is not on bottom, on reload it is on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same issue if you navigate with the "$location.url(***)" method ?

Comment: for $location.url i should give the html also a ng-controller or? because i used the ngRoute for not use the ngController.

Comment: I wanted you to try '  $location.url("/company");  ' but if you said everything is working on Chrome, that's seems more complicated ..

Comment: but this should also work normally with safari i don't know where is the error that it is not work for this browser, firefox and chrome have no problem